# Vaadin 23 change browser url based on button click in the application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Based on the button click in Vaadin application, I'd like to change the browser URL value. I'd like to add some GET parameters to the URL. Please advise how to implement this with Vaadin 23.

Comment: Do you mean you want to implement something as described here https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/navigation/#passing-data-using-route-parameters?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, something like that, but as far as I understand - I may use this solution when I plan to navigate to the different view? In my case I'd like to stay on the same page, just update the current url (when the user configures search filter) in order to allow user to bookmark it or share with others. How to implement this without navigation to other pages?

Comment: Have you tried https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/updating-url-parameters

Comment: If you navigate to some URL that is matched by the current view, then the view instance will be reused but methods to react to navigation changes, e.g. `setParameter`, will be called again.

Comment: If your problem is solved please provide the solution as the answer. This may be helpful for others. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to update the browser url:

```
String baseUrl = RouteConfiguration.forSessionScope().getUrl(getClass());
String urlWithParameters = baseUrl + //add parameters here
getUI().get().getPage().getHistory().replaceState(null, urlWithParameters);
```